# Listening for Place Label Click

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there an event that is triggered when a place label is clicked?

[image: link]

Comment: You control the events that occur when something is clicked.

Comment: And how is that which has been clicked determined?

Comment: Let's say you have a button. Var button1. Then you have a listener and you have an action it listens for. Then afterwards, when the action is met, a reaction can be triggered. Ill post an example below.

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(button1, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(4);
    } 
  });
```

So in this example, we have a listener (inside the initialize function). And we have our var button1. Whenever button1 is clicked, our map will set its zoom level at 4. Of course, you can change anything that happens inside the function.

Your question asked is there an event triggered when the place label is clicked, and the simple answer is no by default. However you can trigger an event by using this listener.